# DEQUEUE_ARRAY not dequeuing anything?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have an queue and I'm trying to take 20 messages out at once.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT on
DECLARE
  TYPE RAW_ARRAY  IS VARRAY(20) OF RAW(2000);
  v_dequeue_options       DBMS_AQ.dequeue_options_t;
  msg_prop_array        DBMS_AQ.message_properties_array_t := 
                        DBMS_AQ.message_properties_array_t();
  payload_array         RAW_ARRAY;
  msgid_array           DBMS_AQ.msgid_array_t;
  retval                PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  
  retval := DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_ARRAY( 
              queue_name               => 'my_queue',
              dequeue_options          => v_dequeue_options,
              array_size               => 20,
              message_properties_array => msg_prop_array,
              payload_array            => payload_array,
              msgid_array              => msgid_array);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of messages dequeued: ' || retval);
END;
```

This is as far as I can see just following the example here (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adque/aq-operations-using-pl-sql.html#GUID-0B018200-824D-458D-98E7-7445AF8B628F).

However, it's always returning

> Number of messages dequeued: 0

And nothign is removed from the queue.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - also, this is how I'm queuing the messages

```
DECLARE
                        v_en_options DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
                        v_en_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
                        v_en_message_handle RAW(16);
                        v_payload RAW(2000) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Test Message');
                        BEGIN
                        DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(
                            queue_name => 'my_queue',
                            enqueue_options => v_en_options,
                            message_properties => v_en_message_properties,
                            payload => v_payload,
                            msgid => v_en_message_handle
                        );
                        COMMIT;
                        END;
```